# Python Selenium with Firefox - Download window is not disabled

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm learning about selenium, write the code below on Jupyter Lab, I'm finding it difficult to download files without the download manager window appearing.
I've tried everything, but I couldn't solve the problem, I'm using the latest version of Anaconda and the latest geckdriver, my firefox is also the most current.
Would you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

options = Options()
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.alwaysOpenPanel", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",1)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream,application/word")

Browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

Browser.get("https://www.microsoft.com/investor/reports/ar22/download-center/")

Browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download-center"]/p[2]/a[2]').click()
```

Comment: I think it will always appear now... shouldn't prevent your scripts from running though.  If it's prompting for a folder, you may want to set that... I use the following:  FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadDir);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "...");  options.setProfile(profile);